# How to use postgres sql meta commands in DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I see postgres provides few handy meta commands that can used from psql (shell?). I have tried using them DBeaver GUI console but they don't work.

Is there a way to use these meta command like `\d` (display all db's), `\dt` (display all tables) etc in DBeaver.

I am using postgres db 13.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

Those aren't "PostgreSQL meta commands". Those are **psql** meta commands and only work inside the command line client `psql`

From within a DBMS independent SQL client like DBeaver you can only run [SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) (or things specific to that SQL tool)

Comment: `Those are psql meta commands and only work inside the command line client psql` - would have been nice if they were at DB level.. but that clarifies. +1